# Identical versions [semver] and [semantic-versioning]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[semver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semver) is short for [semantic-versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic-versioning), both being used for semantic versioning following the spec at http://semver.org.

Normally, I would simply re-tag the 23 question in the first to the latter (57), but in this case I think a synonym from the shorter (the abbreviation used for the domain name) to the latter (the full name, which also has the tag-wiki) would be useful.

So, could a mod please sponsor a synonym?