# [cyberglove]: delete, leave, or alias to some motion-capture-related tag? [motion]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just stumbled on tag [cyberglove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyberglove) which is (one) brand of motion-capture glove. The tag has one question and [6 plaintext questions mentioning cyberglove](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cyberglove+is%3Aq).

I have no idea what to do, should we:

- Delete
- Leave
- Alias to a motion-capture tag?

  - if so, should that be [motion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/motion) or do we need to create [motion-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/motion-capture)? For reference, there are [645 questions mentioning motion-capture](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=motion-capture+is%3Aq); but most of those are about motion capture from video only; not hardware/sensors/peripherals. Anyone actually familiar with this area who can comment on tags?
  - But when I search, there are 0 questions on "motion-capture glove" or "motion glove". Unless they are asked under proprietary names.

(Btw, beware of confusion with the totally unrelated NLP word-vector algorithm and software [GloVe (Global Vectors for Word Representation)](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) and the tag[python-glove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-glove). (Shouldn't have been named python-, but that's another story))

Comment: We already have [tag:mo-cap], so no need for [tag:motion-capture], at least. Perhaps that's a good synonym, though, the abbreviation might not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth: a) [mo-cap] is impossible to discover unless you know the jargon, hence b) [motion-capture] should be an alias to [mo-cap] or vice versa c) [mo-cap] lacks a tag description, I presume that's "motion-capture" in general, not just from hardware.

Comment: Similar to the case of ["Identical versions \[semver\] and \[semantic-versioning\]"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300398/identical-versions-semver-and-semantic-versioning), where the (hard-to-find jargon) abbreviation is an alias to the unabbreviated name